# In sveltekit, How can I get "load's fetch" from client side code?(like *.svelte)

Tags: hook, fetch-api, server-side, client-side, sveltekit

I'm making private homepage working only for login user.
When user login success, API server return token and save it to cookie.

After that, token was added to all fetch's request header at server-side "handleFetch" hooks.

All works fine with server-side rendering. But At client-side rendering needed position, I can't use "load's fetch" and also can't get token from cookies by default sveltekit functionality.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Any way to do this? In Addition, when auth token was expired refresh token was used to receive new. This logic included in server-side hooks.